# tinyMCE deletes background-image:"" content with magento like urls

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento, tinymce

I have cms block in magento where one div element have style property with backgroud-image and value is magento style URL

```
<div class="contain-wide" style="background-image: url('{{media url="wysiwyg/spare-parts.jpg"}}')">
```

problem is when I turn on wysiwyg editor this line gets edited to

```
<div class="contain-wide" wysiwyg="" spare-parts="" jpg="">
```

and no longer is valid inline css.

things I tried are adding these settings to /js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

```
        cleanup_on_startup: false,
        trim_span_elements: false,
        verify_html: false,
        cleanup: false,
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

unfortunately that only disables html verification, css is still edited auto by tinyMCE.

Comment: i guess it has to do with the quotes, best is to set the full path to image or set it via a class , you can even tune tinymce for this adding a preset rule

Comment: that is the worst not best. you wont be able to use cdn and switch it on/off (change media urls), or adding image background will require to edit stylesheet all the time.

Comment: **via a class, you only need to update your css file**. search for custom formats or formats in tinymce and update either the style select or format of your customized tinymce. thats how i do , so the writer does not destroy the design and just pickups the adequat tag while writing. css is applied once page is loaded. change or remove  the style sheet then it looks totally different. excuse my average english , hope you see my point.

Comment: and client is always willing to pay 100$ for css update just because he needs to change background image for block. you are not helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able, via the wysiwyg, to select part of the page then click on `insert/edit attributes` (on the last line of tinymce tools, there is a hand on top of a little box) in which you should be able to edit attributes and maybe make what you need.

This will in fact crate a div for you and in this pop-up box you can select which style you want on this div.

**Edit** : but as @GCyrillus commented on your question I would recommend you to do it via style, because that would means an admin only wanting to edit the content could break the site visual layout.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the MCE use a direct path.  ie. src="http(s)://yourimage.jpg">

Comment: meaning upload the image in the root and call upon it, this should kill the conflict with the tinyMCE